# Factory Pattern with Multiple Inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

In this problem I have three pure virtual classes, let's name them **A, B, C**. Each of them provides a different set of functionality. I have another pure virtual class that I will call **CommonInterface** that does not introduce any new functionality but inherits A, B, and C to make them reachable through a single interface as below:

```
class CommonInterface : public virtual A, public virtual B, public virtual C
```

**These interfaces are defined by a standard document and are not subject to change.** They are defined as a factory design pattern, such that, anyone can implement the functionality of CommonInterface according to their needs.

My role is to provide a built-in implementation to this CommonInterface, so that people can use my implementation in case the built-in implementation of the interface is good enough for them. I want to design the built-in implementation well but I am not very sure how to apply the factory pattern to multiple inheritance cases. My current implementation implements each base interface as

```
class BuiltinA : public A
class BuiltinB : public B
class BuiltinC : public C
```

and then implements common interface as given below:

```
class BuiltinImplementation : public virtual CommonInterface, public BuiltinA, public BuiltinB, public BuiltinC
```

Is this a good or bad design? If it is a bad design, how can I improve it? Also is there any patterns I can apply to this case? Any expert opinion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the way to create a god class there ... which is something that is worth avoiding if you can.  Hard to say more though since it's so generic.

Comment: By pure virtual classes, do you mean abstract classes ? Why are you using virtual inheritance ? A, B and C may have common bases that you want them to share ?

Comment: @Caninonos yes, I meant abstract class. I read a little bit about virtual inheritance and that's apparently a mistake so I'm updating it.

Answer (score 0):

A CommonInterface of three classes should give you access to methods, that are purely common between all three classes and **hide** class specific interfaces. Your implementation of the CommonInterface gives the caller access to **all class specific** methods. I would consider this already a bad design.

I would propose to change the inheritance to:

```
class CommonInterface {
   public:
      virtual void common_method(<args>) = 0;
};

class A : public CommonInterface {
   public:
      virtual void a_specific_method(<args>) = 0;
};

class B : public CommonInterface {
   public:
      virtual void b_specific_method(<args>) = 0;
};
```

And your implementation of builtin is:

```
class Builtin_A : public A {
    [...]
};

class Builtin_B : public B {
    [...]
};
```

Comment: I already mentioned at the beginning of second paragraph that A, B, C and CommonInterface are not defined by me but by a standard document and unfortunately, I am not allowed to make any changes in that part. If I could change it, I wouldn't have to look for a solution.

Comment: Your question was, if you have a good or a bad design. IMHO you already start with a bad design (which you can't change) and you will always end with a bad design.

Comment: True that, but it is beyond my authorization, unfortunately.